Spring boot 3 and SOAP dependencies in gradle
I upgraded my spring boor project to spring boot version 3.3.2
Now I need to add SOAP client. I extended WebServiceGatewaySupport.
(import org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport;)

In order to enable WebServiceGatewaySupport, I need to add this in my build.gradle file:
implementation'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
After trying clean / build options (I am using Intellij IDEA), I am getting this error:
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jakarta.servlet.ServletRegistration.getClassName()" because "registration" is null

Any idea what is going on?
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.8.0'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-security:1.8.0'
    implementation'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'

I was trying to exclude:
exclude group: org.springframework.boot, module: spring-boot-starter-tomcat
But it did not work.
